# MS Access Report Formatting

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have an access report that has two grouping levels, for the most part it works great, but occasionally the detail is too long and the final total prints on a page all by itself.  The client would like to move the last detail record to the next page when that happens so the total is not by itself.  I know in other reporting tools this is relatively simple... but so far I have not been able to figure out how to do it in Access...

Does anyone have any ideas or has anyone done this before?

Group by Project Name 
   Group by Project Phase - this footer has the total 
      Group on Change Order - this footer has a subtotal for each group

The subtotal seems to always stay with the current record, but I cannot figure out how to keep the project phase with the last 'change order' group....

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Look at the KEEP TOGETHER property of your group footer. This may or may not do the job, but it's the feature designed to fix this issue. You also may want to check the REPEAT property, which can help make a report more readable.

Answer (score 0):

In report design view, open "Sorting and Grouping" (from menu or toolbar).  Select the group level you want to control, which is probably the bottom-most. Set "Keep Together" to "Whole Group", or possibly "With First Detail."